# Android aSmack XMPP filetransfer always shows in progress and status 0

Tags: android, chat, file-transfer, asmack, quickblox

i m developing a chat app in which i need to send images between peer to peer chat users. For now i m able to send image and my filereceiver also accepts request and start receiving file.

But printing status always keep printing:
**LOG:**  Progress: 0.0 & Status: In Progress

And after finishing thread -
**LOG** ###Filetransfer not complete. Status:In Progress

If i make this thread run removing count it continuesly keep printing - Progress: 0.0 & Status: In Progress

Sometimes full image is received later .. that takes long time and many times half or size 0.

```
private ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm;    
 if (sdm == null)
                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
                Log.v("---fileReceive----","after discover connectin.....");
                sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
                sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());                    
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
                ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());

                sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);


                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
                FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true; 
                manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
                // Create the listener
                //  fListner=new FileTransferListener() {
                manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.v("----Recieve File",
                                "new file transfere requesttttt------------");

                        Log.v("-----file request","from" + request.getRequestor());

                        // Accept it

                        try {
                            IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                            Log.v("----transfer--","accepted");

                            double percents = 0.0;
                            int currentCycle = 0;
                            transfer.recieveFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+transfer.getFileName()));


                              while(!transfer.isDone() && currentCycle < 100) {
                                    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.in_progress)) {
                                        percents = ((int) (transfer.getProgress()*10000)) / 100.0;
                                                  //percents is 100.0 after 1 cycle
                                        Log.i(LOG, "Filetransfer Progress: "+percents + " Status: "+transfer.getStatus().toString());
                                    } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                                        Log.e(LOG, "FileTransfer ERROR"+transfer.getError().getMessage());
                                        break;
                                    } 
                                    currentCycle ++;
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.complete)) {
                                    if (onFileReceivedListener != null) {
                                       onFileReceivedListener.onFileReceived(transfer);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    Log.e(LOG, "###Filetransfer not complete. Status:" + transfer.getStatus().toString());
                                                        //FILE IS HERE  
                                }
                        } catch (XMPPException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }); `
```

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: What Chat server do you use?

Comment: It's not really an answer but a good starting point: https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/aSmack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: @Vyoma have you done this task?

Answer (score 0):

I did have a little experience with asmack and smackx lately, and can't be too positive about them.

I do not know exactly where your problem comes from, but i can tell you it's normal. You'll first get a load of progress = 0 before any progress actually starts.
If it is a small file you're sending, it then just sends so quickly that there isn't any real progress.

However, if you successfully send a larger file, this function does work pretty good and will give you the rough progress.

In the end we concluded that this functionality simply was to buggy and limited and implemented our own filetransfer xmpp message and handle sending it via our own server. Like that you can also send files to offline people, in groups (MUC) and show a decent progress on both sides (sending & receiving).

Comment: Thanks 4 ur response. Actually right now i get size 0 for 6.71 kb of image. And coudnt implement own server. Can u plz share ur working code if i can get any prob. from my side.

Comment: Sorry that working code is gone I think, since we've changed it to use our own server. 
However, like i said, try it with pictures of a couple of MBs. 6kb is send too fast.

Comment: I tried image of mbs but as i said for any image at receiver side it shows image size 0. That means its saved but not fully received.